# Upgrade from spring-security-saml2-core 1.0.10.RELEASE to 2.0.0.M31 leads to missing import errors

Tags: java, spring-security, migration, saml, opensaml

I'm working on upgrading **`spring-security-saml2-core`** from version **`1.0.10.RELEASE`** to **`2.0.0.M31`** in my project. I don't want to switch to the newer spring-security-library. After the upgrade, I face the following missing import errors on compilation:

- **`org.opensaml.saml2.metadata`** (from **`org.opensaml:opensaml:2.6.6`** jar)
- **`org.opensaml.xml`** (from **`org.opensaml:xmltooling:1.4.4`** jar)
- **`org.opensaml.xml.security`** (from **`org.opensaml:xmltooling:1.4.4`** jar)
- **`org.opensaml.xml.signature`** (from **`org.opensaml:xmltooling:1.4.4`** jar)
- **`org.springframework.security.saml.key`** (from **`org.springframework.security.extensions:spring-security-saml2-core:1.0.10.RELEASE`** jar)
- **`org.springframework.security.saml.metadata`** (from **`org.springframework.security.extensions:spring-security-saml2-core:1.0.10.RELEASE`** jar)
- **`org.opensaml.xml.security.credential`** (from **`org.opensaml:xmltooling:1.4.4`** jar)
- **`org.springframework.security.providers`** (from **`org.springframework.security.extensions:spring-security-saml2-core:1.0.10.RELEASE`** jar)
- **`org.opensaml.saml2.core`** (from **`org.opensaml:opensaml:2.6.6`** jar)
- **`org.springframework.security.saml.userdetails`** (from **`org.springframework.security.extensions:spring-security-saml2-core:1.0.10.RELEASE`** jar)

These missing imports are crucial for my application, and I'm unable to compile the code without resolving them.

I was expecting the migration to be straightforward, but unfortunately, that was not the case. I've looked for migration documentation to help with the transition, but the only document available is the **[SAML 2.0 Migration Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/SAML-2.0-Migration-Guide)**. However, it's poorly written and doesn't suggest alternate packages for the ones that have changed.
Good example doc:https://restsharp.dev/v107/#reference

I expected to find a clear and concise migration path, including the necessary package replacements. Now, I'm stuck with these compilation errors and unsure how to proceed.

Can anyone point me to the alternatives or solutions for these missing imports? Any help or guidance on this migration would be greatly appreciated.